# Can we install two Mysql's with different port on single pc?

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have an problem with my web project. I am using a database which dynamically creates a new database for every new user so he or she can see his or her information. So I want that this web project use another individual MySQL. Is it possible to install two MySQLs in single system? If yes then how is it possible?

Comment: I've done it accidentally, so yes, it's possible. both databases worked perfectly well, but my code was trying to connect to the wrong one. just a matter of configuring each one individually.

Comment: [Check out this page of the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqld-multi.html)

Answer (score 4):

It can be done, but it is a complicated thing to setup.

I recommend instead rethinking this setup.  The job of the RDBMS is to store data and separate access to it based on grants you have setup.  It is common to run many different databases on one MySQL instance (or any other RDBMS).  If you *must* create a different database for each user, you might consider just adding a prefix to the database name indicating that it is a part of this web application, and is a user database. That will be easier to manage in the long run than multiple MySQL instances.

#### However,

The other thing to rethink is if every user really needs a separate database. Typically in a web application, all information for all users is stored in a *single* database, with some column or columns identifying the user who owns the row. It is much easier to query against a single database than multiple databases, when you need to do reporting against your site data.  It is also far easier to maintain than multiple databases, should you need to make schema changes and have to propagate them across *n* site user databases.

Comment: Dear Michael. I am agree with your answer but how can we create instances of MySQL ?

Comment: @chandan It depends on your platform see http://serverfault.com/search?q=mysql+multiple+instances